# Нужно войти в биос со статусом администратора. Простой вход не позволяет изменять настройки

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, bios, uefi

Ноутбук asus, amd a6; версия биос American Magatrends Inc. X540BA.303, 04.07.2019 Режим биос UEFI

Хочу установить линукс, для этого нужен boot, у меня он не работает без статуса администратора

Т.е. после нажатий клавиши f2 я захожу в биос но не могу ничего изменить в нем даже зайти в boot. Могу переключаться между вкладками но настройки которые нужны горят серым цветом. На главной странице явно видно что я зашёл как user а так же можно как администратор но я не знаю как. Помогите я ничего не могу в нем сделать. Клавиши alt+r+f9 не работают

Comment: в биосе Security/Administator Password, наверное надо сделать пустым, да и User тоже

Comment: В Биосе я не могу изменять пароль администратора, только юзера, поэтому сделать его пустым не получается

Comment: Тогда гугли как сбпросить пароль на твоём ноуте. В старых версиях достаточно было вытащить батарейку-таблетку. В современных - возможно надо добраться до переключателя на материнке. Всё индивидуально.