# Может ли сброс компа до заводских настроек сбросить и настройки биос?

Tags: linux, windows, bios, uefi

Это надо для сброса биос. Он не разрешает мне использовать права администратора.

Comment: А что вы имеете в виду под "сброс компа"? Если это сброс операционной системы, так это затронет только каталог самой операционной системы. Настройки BIOS хранятся в энергонезависимой памяти и никак не связаны с операционной системой. Сбросить настройки BIOS можно через извлечение батарейки энергонезависимой памяти.

Comment: *"Он не разрешает мне использовать права администратора."* - поподробнее и с картинками. биос вообще никаким боком к правам администратора в системе. @user_1234567890 Память потому и называется энергонезависимой, что при извлечении батареек данные не теряются. От этого разве что часы сбросятся.

Comment: @user7860670, она же не сможет хранить вечность. Временами ей нужна "подпитка". Другой вопрос, что это "временами" - не день-два. Ну, и в свете этих уточнений мой комментарий действительно теряет смысл. Спасибо.

Comment: @user_1234567890 Не нужна ей никакая подпитка. С SSD и карт памяти же ничего со временем не пропадает безо всякой подпитки.

Comment: а зачем под разными именами вопросы задавать? шифруетесь? [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1490275/178576), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1490445/178576)

Comment: продолжение вопросов из того же источника: [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1490161/178576), [4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1490228/178576), [5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1490529/178576)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: чтоб экзаминатор не спалил)